# Seeking windows based C unit test system that works right out of the box (preferably with Netbeans)

Tags: c, unit-testing, netbeans

I tried Check, but there isnt much documentation (especially about windows) and I keep getting segfaults (probably because I am unsure of what defines are required).

I can't get Cunit to build and install with Cygwn (Make crashes on a virgin install (error message lost as I have since trashed it but I did google).

Even NetBeans "simple c unit test" is segfaulting on me.

---

Can anyone tell me of a C unit test system which will work right out of the box without me having to spend hours googling & debugging  and days on support forums?

Anything at all - I will use any compiler (Migw, Borland, Cygwin ... anything)

Desirable would be integration with Netbeans, but I can live wthout that.

Desirable would be a nice GUI, maybe with a traffic light system, but I can live wthout that.

I just want to get on with it & feel that I might be quicker hacking together my own ...

Any suggestins? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using [Boost Test library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html). It is in C++ though and the documentation is not very good. The upside is that it is widely used and many continuous integration tools like [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) can parse its output format and visualize test results as plots.

Comment: +1 despite "though and the documentation is not very good" ;-)  I rate Boost highly. I am trying to keep away from C++ testers like Booos or CppUnit. Also anything too complex. Just an out of the box pass/fail thingy - preferably traffic-light.  For what I am doing, I don't need suites & fixtures & fancy whatnots ...   (still Boos, or GoogleTest or CppUnit are all contenders - if they]don't need (too much) configuration and/or too much fancy set-up in the test-harness)

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently developping C++ apps on windows, and I also had a look around for unit test framework that could work with what we do, i.e. native code.

I came across `WinUnit`, developed by someone from M$ a while ago to deal with native code.
It's very easy to get started with, you just need to create a specific DLL project per test suite and then use the winunit.exe to launch the tests.

The nice thing about it, is that you dont need to take care about all the init test-suite parts, just write your unit tests as functions, in a DLL and launch WinUnit!

It's a CLI version, no flashy GUI here but it does the job.
It's also straightforward to add as an external tool to VisualStudio.

have a look here for more details:
http://winunit.codeplex.com/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc136757.aspx

I've previsouly used CUnit for a Linux based OS without any trouble, but havent really tried it on Windows platform.

Comment: +1 thanks, I will check it out. I have previously used CppUnit (on Windows), but for some reason (after a few years away) everything I try is an uphill struggle.  I may well end up coding my own. I'll get back to you as soon as I try it

Comment: Hmmm, "Creating a test project involves just creating a DLL. Here's how to do it in Visual Studio 2008..." Maybe not for C purists, but I can accept that if it works

Comment: the DLL is just a placeholder for unit test functions, and dynamically loaded by winunit at runtime. In your test function, that can be pure C or C++, doesnt matter.